# Programmatically create user and add complete address field values

Tags: 8

I have an address field on my User entities.  I want to programmatically create users and set their address field values, I currently have this:

```
 $values = [
  'mail' => 'chris+7asd7fadf7afdafasdf@example.com',
  'name' => 'chris+7asd7fadf7afdafasdf@example',
  'first_name' => 'First',
  'last_name' => 'Last',
  'roles' => [],
  'pass' => user_password(),
  'status' => 1,
];
$user = User::create($values);
$user->field_contact_information->country = 'US';
$user->field_contact_information->given_name = $values['first_name'];
$user->field_contact_information->family_name = $values['last_name'];
$user->save();
```

But it's not saving the values to `field_contact_information`.  Elsewhere in the app, I do access these values with `$user->field_contact_information->given_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was simple - it should be `$user->field_contact_information->country_code = 'US';`

Comment: You can always see the column names by looking at the field class (e.g. AddressItem) and its property definitions